# zimbra zimlet to upload files in a briefcase folder from backend

Tags: javascript, jsp, zimbra

I am creating a zimlet using js to generate a tree folder structure, but I also need it to include some files (default ones that are on the server). The problem is that I can't find a way to do this without asking the user to select the files manually. Any help on this?

Answer (score 2):

You should check the zimbra soap which is realy helpful to you. I think you get the soap which upload the file in brifcase folder.